# onClick="" don't appear at the actual element made with react.

Tags: javascript, html, web, reactjs

I'm making some elements with react like this:

```
var AddNewTask = React.createClass({
  handleClick: function() {
   console.log('pressed!');
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="addNewTask" onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <i className="material-icons">add</i>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

but on the actual rendered html page this div does not contain onClick property. Just looks like this.

```
<div class="addNewTask" data-reactid=".0.2">
  <i class="material-icons"  data-reactid=".0.2.0">add</i>
</div>
```

How to make it appear?

Comment: Why do you want it to? It probably just gets translated to a click listener attached to that DOM node.

Comment: i want it to work. Now nothing happens then i click.

Comment: Your component looks fine, if you're not seeing anything in the console then something else probably isn't right.

Comment: @Dylan AddNewTask is inside other component TaskBox. Can this cause the problem?

Comment: Are you working in Node by chance?

Comment: @NickZuber What do you mean? I'm just learning and can't get my button to work :(

Comment: Are there any other errors in your console/terminals?

Comment: @Syberic Ah nevermind - I didn't mean to cause confusion! There's a common issue with new users where React components don't work in Node, but since you're not using Node it doesn't matter

Comment: @NickZuber lol sry, i got you wrong. I'm using Node.

Comment: @Syberic If your React components don't have their functionality, I suspect you aren't completely rendering them on the client. You may just be piping in the HTML without the actual React functionality. Again, it's hard to tell when I can't actually see your problem

Comment: Console shows error:
`Error: Invariant Violation: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's 'render' method, or you have multiple copies of React loaded (details: https://fb.me/react-refs-must-have-owner).`
but i'm not running two react instances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't appear in the rendered HTML, as the handler is attached to the DOM element itself. React also normalizes the event system across browsers so that it behaves consistently. I would suggest reading up on how it works at the official docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html

Comment: yes, it should work fine. See this example (click on _add_ and check your browser's console): http://jsbin.com/fefoxoy/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 3):

Simply put:

1. `onClick` on jsx is not `DOM-onClick-event` but `React-onClick-event`.
2. `React-onClick-event` is belong to React, so it's not displayed on DOM.
3. React.js automatically convert `React-onClick-event` into `DOM-onClick-event` **behind the scene**.