# ReactJS undefined onClick attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm beginner in ReactJS. I add HTML code in a div and this HTML code is for buttons, it's works, but the onClick attribute is always undefined. I tried two things but it doesn't work.

First try :

```js
const createListPlaylist = (res) => {
    if (res === undefined)
        return;
    var list = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < res.data.items.length; i++)
        list += `<Button onClick=${createPlaylistWidget(res.data.items[i].id)}>${res.data.items[i].name}</Button><br>`;
    document.getElementById("PlayListViewer").innerHTML += list;
}
```

Second try :

```js
const createListPlaylist = (res) => {
    if (res === undefined)
        return;
    var list = "";
    var listArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < res.data.items.length; i++) {
        listArray.push(createPlaylistWidget(res.data.items[i].id));
        list += `<button onClick=${displayPlaylitSelected(listArray[i])}>${res.data.items[i].name}</button><br>`;
    }
    document.getElementById("PlayListViewer").innerHTML += list;
}
```

Result :

[image: Result of the reactJS code in the HTML]

`createListPlaylist` is called after an axios request and the `res` parameter is the response of the request and yes `res.data.items[i].id` is correct I can print in in the console with no problem. So, ask your help because I don't no why my `onClick` attribute is undefined and I don't find the answer.

Thank you in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass functions to events inside {} in React;

```
...
.... onClick={()=>${.....}}
```

see below for more information;

https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score 0):

It's `onClick` and not `onclick`. Amend that change and it will work.

Pretty much all the props in react should be written in camelCase. Incase you want the element to appear in dom then you can write it in lowercase.

Also note, there is an exception for `aria-*` attributes and `data-*` data attributes to this case.

Comment: It is actually `onClick` in React, but `onclick` in plain HTML.

Comment: Correct my friend but the reason it is appearing in the HTML Dom here is because it has been passed in lowercase. If it's passed as camelCase (onClick), then it won't appear in the screenshot.

Comment: @Knick, it is already passed camelCase, it renders lower case in HTML tho

Comment: If you inspect a react project you will not see any `onclick` attributes in the HTML. You see it here because the button is not React, its a string literal.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34913367/9381601) for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

### JSX is not HTML

You cannot make a string of JSX and expect it to behave as a component or use JSX syntax. JSX is just a cleaner/easier way of writing JavaScript function calls (specifically `React.createElement()`.

Unfortunately there is no simple fix to the code you provided it will require you to re-approach the problem thinking in React, but I can point out the problem areas.

1. You cannot treat strings as components.
2. When using react using `document.getElementById().innerHTML` is almost always an anti-pattern.
3. When assigning an event handler in React, you must pass it a function *reference*, you are instead *calling* a function and assigning its return value to `onClick`.